# Create thumbnail file when cropping and converting in FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm currently using the following:

```
ffmpeg -y -i input.mov -i watermark.png -filter_complex "[0:v]crop=iw-0:ih-440,scale=480:640[bg];[bg][1:v]overlay=W-w-10:H-h-10" output.mp4
```

To resize, crop and watermark a video, all is working perfectly, however I'd like to grab a screenshot midway through. I've tried adding:

```
-qscale:v 2 thumbnail.jpg
```

After the input.mov, however it then ruins the rest of the script. Bit of a noob to FFMpeg.

EDIT:

The following:

```
ffmpeg -y -i input.mov -vframes 1 -q:v 2 thumbnail.jpg -i watermark.png -filter_complex "[0:v]crop=iw-0:ih-440,scale=480:640[bg];[bg][1:v]overlay=W-w-10:H-h-10" output.mp4
```

Creates the thumbnail and creates output.mp4, but not cropped or with the thumbnail. I'm assuming the thumbnail creation needs to go in that same sequence?

Comment: You say *midway*, so do you know the duration of the main video?

Comment: @Gyan They can be variable lengths, but just the 10th frame for example would be fine. Even the first frame really... The code I've got creates the thumbnail but then doesn't apply the filters to the video.

Comment: use ffprobe, get duration, then loop over and get screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the 10th frame is fine, then you can use

`ffmpeg -y -i input.mov -i watermark.png -filter_complex "[0:v]crop=iw-0:ih-440,scale=480:640[bg];[bg][1:v]overlay=W-w-10:H-h-10,split=2[v][pic];[pic]trim=start_frame=10[pic]" -map "[v]" -map 0:a? output.mp4 -vframes 1 -map "[pic]" out.jpg`

If you know the midway duration, e.g. 12.5s, then your trim arg can be `trim=st=12.5`

(If you're on a shell where [] are special characters, use single quotes for mapping)

Comment: Thanks for this, however it gets the following: `Output with label 'pic' does not exist in any defined filter graph, or was already used elsewhere.`

Comment: Removed `[pic]trim=start_frame=10`and got the error `[AVFilterGraph @ 0x5582faf5f9c0] No such filter: '' Error initializing complex filters. Invalid argument`

Comment: Right, sort of success... Outputs both the thumbnail and the video, but the video has no audio?!